# Can Amazon Glacier mirror an Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to mirror an S3 bucket with Amazon Glacier.

The [Glacier FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/) states:

> Amazon S3 now provides a new storage option that enables you to
>   utilize Amazon Glacier’s extremely low-cost storage service for data
>   archiving. You can define S3 lifeycycle rules to automatically archive
>   sets of Amazon S3 objects to Amazon Glacier to reduce your storage
>   costs. You can learn more by visiting the Object Lifecycle Management
>   topic in the Amazon S3 Developer Guide.

This is close, but I'd like to *mirror*. I do not want to delete the content on S3, only copy it to Glacier.

Is this possible to setup automatically with AWS?

Or does this mirroring need be uploaded to Glacier manually?

Comment: I'd like this feature, too. I don't think it exists now, though.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by mirroring S3 to Glacier?

Comment: @EricHammond I'm trying backup my S3 files on Glacier.

Comment: I don't think Glacier is generally an appropriate place to create backup copies of S3 objects (where you keep copies in both places).  I explain more in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231733/aws-ways-of-keeping-cost-down-while-backing-up-s3-files-to-glacier/15234873#15234873

Comment: I'd would like that feature also in order to increase the availability of the data stored in S3.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is now possible to achieve an S3 to Glacier "mirror" by first creating a cross-region replication bucket on Amazon S3 (this replication bucket will be a mirror of your original bucket - see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html), then setting up a life-cycle rule (to move the data to Glacier) from within the *replication* bucket.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon doesn't offer this feature through its API. We had the same problem, and solved the problem by running a daily cron job that re-uploads files to Glacier.

Here is a snippet of code you can run using Python and boto to copy a file to a Glacier vault. Note that with the code below, you do have to download the file locally from S3 before you can run it (you can use s3cmd, for instance) - the following code is useful for uploading the local file to Glacier.

```py
import boto

# Set up your AWS key and secret, and vault name
aws_key = "AKIA1234"
aws_secret = "ABC123"
glacierVault = "someName"

# Assumption is that this file has been downloaded from S3
fileName = "localfile.tgz"

try: 
  # Connect to boto
  l = boto.glacier.layer2.Layer2(aws_access_key_id=aws_key, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret)

  # Get your Glacier vault
  v = l.get_vault(glacierVault)

  # Upload file using concurrent upload (so large files are OK)
  archiveID = v.concurrent_create_archive_from_file(fileName)

  # Append this archiveID to a local file, that way you remember what file
  # in Glacier corresponds to a local file. Glacier has no concept of files.
  open("glacier.txt", "a").write(fileName + " " + archiveID + "\n")
except:
  print "Could not upload gzipped file to Glacier"
```

Answer (score 4):

This is done via [Lifecycle policy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/archive-s3-to-glacier/), but the object is not available in S3 anymore. You can duplicate it into separate bucket to keep it.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it was removed ? Or where I can find the info about it being removed ?

Answer (score 0):

If you first enable versioning on your S3 bucket then lifecycle rules can be applied to previous versions. This will achieve a very similar outcome, except there won't be a backup of the current version.